# Is it proper to use "I" in a privacy policy?

Tags: privacy

I am creating a privacy policy for an app that I have developed by myself. Since there is no other person legally responsible, is it ok if I use the word "I" in the privacy policy?
Extra info:

- This app will be on the app store and google play store
- "I" refers to me (the creator of the app)

Example:

> ***I*** use analytics services to analyze how users use the app. These services may track how long users use the app, what pages inside the
>   app users visit, and errors users encounter.

Comment: Make sure you define what/who exactly "I" refers to.

Comment: I would refer to me, I'll add that to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is legal, there is nothing requiring you to pretend to be a company or group of people. Whether you want to disclose your solo status in this way is a question. It might seem more businesslike to say

> the owner uses analytics services

but that is a matter of style, not of law.

Comment: Is it also known to refer to the program's name instead of "I", "We", "Owner"?

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly acceptable. After all, a privacy policy is about being truthful and transparent about what happens to the data of the people using your application. 
I would add to Dave's answer that the information about the "I" is relevant. Depending on your target audience, you might need to disclose quite clearly who the entity I is.

Under GDPR for sure, "The name and contact details of your organisation." are required. Even if you aren't targeting Europeans, reading through the catalogue of disclosure requirements is an educational experience:

https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/individual-rights/right-to-be-informed/